# Add minutes to timestamp string

Tags: java-8

Very primitive question.

```
String startTime = "2020-07-15T17:35:00Z";
```

I want to add 3.5 hours to this string. Timezone is UTC. How should i do that ?

I tried going through TemporalAccessor and DateTimeFormatter but no success.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
TemporalAccessor temporalAccessor = formatter.parse(startTime);
final LocalDateTime parse = LocalDateTime.parse(startTime, formatter);
```

Comment: `but no success` what problem you exactly faced ?

Comment: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-07-15T17:35:00Z' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MicroOfSecond=0, MilliOfSecond=0, InstantSeconds=1594834500, NanoOfSecond=0},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String startTimeString = "2020-07-15T17:35:00Z";
final LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startTimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
LocalDateTime endTime = startTime.plusHours(3).plusMinutes(30);
String endTimeString = endTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

Comment: How do you convert back the endTime to the format of startTimeString ?

Comment: I added it to the answer @Prakhar

Comment: Yeah i mean but Z in the end which means UTC does not come as output. Is there a way to do add that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse from string to `Instant` and then add 3.5 hour. Then again format into the string.

```
String startTime = "2020-07-15T17:35:00Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
Instant instant = Instant.from(formatter.parse(startTime));
instant = instant.plusSeconds((3*60*60)+(30*60));
startTime = formatter.format(instant);
```

Output:

```
2020-07-15T21:05:00Z
```

Comment: @Prakhar Now it converts with `Z` in string